best practise for - select with joined tables with some where filter - direct mapping (jpa) or native sql
I want to collect data from two tables (one-to-many relationship). In most cases for one record in first table there are two records in second.
In my case I want to filter records from second table.
Native SQL would look like this.
SELECT *
FROM X 
JOIN Y ON X.id= Y.id
WHERE Y.specificField = 'value';

And the question is - what should I use - best practice in this case - native sql or rather use pure JPA with entity with added field (relation one to many).
Looks like in case jpa mapping all filtering will be done in my app not db - are there any tricks to do filtering when gathering data from two tables  with entity usage ?

i learn good engineer's attitude from your question. thank you
i have done some test and think about your question.
i think using jpa is better option , because using native sql has some issue.

if database change, there's possibility that we should update sql for changed database
hard to map result of query into entity object, OOP might be harder.
applying transaction is hard, jpa provide robust transaction manager
validation is hard.

i have done some test and figure out jpa use optimized query so that prevent our spring boot app does not have to do some extra processing (filtering mapping)
here is the code
class X
@Entity
@Getter
@NoArgsConstructor(access = AccessLevel.PROTECTED)
@AllArgsConstructor
public class X {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;
    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY, orphanRemoval = true, mappedBy = "parent")
    private List<Y> children = new ArrayList<>();

}

class Y
@Entity
@Getter
@NoArgsConstructor(access = AccessLevel.PROTECTED)
@AllArgsConstructor
@Builder
public class Y {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;
    private String name;
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "x_id")
    private X parent;
}

repository x
public interface XRepository extends JpaRepository<X, Long> {
    @Query("select distinct x from X x left join fetch x.children y where y.name =:name")
    Optional<X> getXAndChildOnlyWithName(@Param("name") final String name);
}

test
@Slf4j
@SpringBootTest
@Transactional
class XRepositoryTest {
    @Autowired
    XRepository xRepository;
    @Autowired
    YRepository yRepository;

    @PostConstruct
    void init() {
        X x = new X();
        X saved = xRepository.saveAndFlush(x);
        Y y1 = Y.builder()
                .name("t")
                .parent(saved)
                .build();
        Y y2 = Y.builder()
                .name("x")
                .parent(saved)
                .build();
        Y y3 = Y.builder()
                .name("t")
                .parent(saved)
                .build();
        yRepository.saveAllAndFlush(List.of(y1, y2, y3));
    }


    @Test
    void getChildJoin() {
        final X findX = xRepository.getXAndChildOnlyWithName("t").orElseThrow();
        List<Y> children = findX.getChildren();
        for(final Y child : children){
            log.info(child.getName());
        }
    }
}

the result query that jpa generated is quite optimized
result image
so i think using jpa with fetch join is quite practical practice

but looks like You defined / suggest  to spring how query should be build ->
@Query("select distinct x from X x left join fetch x.children y where y.name =:name")     Optional<X> getXAndChildOnlyWithName(@Param("name") final String name); }

string "select distinct x from X x left join fetch x.children y where y.name =:name" inside @Query annotation is JPQL that JPA use to build SQL for database we use when we flush our entitymanager state.
so  using JPQL does not make application bounded by specific database
thank you :)

If you don't like using Strings in JPQL because it can lead to human errors, consider using QueryDSL. With QueryDSL, you can programmatically generate the desired SQL without using Strings, allowing you to detect errors at compile time. It might be worth trying it out.

oh may be I misunderstood Your comment,
The reason I wrote additional JPQL is to prevent extra queries caused by lazy loading, which occurs due to the Fetch.LAZY setting in the @OneToMany annotation. I used a fetch join inside jpql to load the Y associated with X in a single query.

You can add where clause in joined tables with queries derived from method names inside repository using underscores after field relating to other entity.
Assuming thath entities are defined as in previous lux00leo answer your repository can be like this:
@Repository
public interface XRepository extends JpaRepository<X, Long> {
    Optional<X> findByChildren_Name(String name);
}

Calling findByChildren_Name method the result will be the same as previous answer, but here you don't write any explicit query (neither SQL native or JPQL)
